# How do I prevent scientific notation on a plot and add a trend line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I like to show the numbers in decimal 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, .. 0.10 rather than scientific notation.  Is this possible?

Also, didn't mean to add a secondary question but each time I try adding a trend line, it doesn't work.  Any advice on that is appreciated as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns}
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

**.. snip**

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{exp24_fig2.eps}
\end{center}
\section*{Results}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{axis}[
title={Ballistic Galvanometer Calibration},
xlabel={Capacitance ($\mu$F)},
ylabel={Deflectance (cm)},
xmin=0.01, xmax=0.10,
ymin=2, ymax=17,
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
yminorgrids=true,
xminorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
 ]
 coordinates {
  (0.01,2)(0.02,4)(0.03,5)(0.04,7)(0.05,8)(0.06,10)(0.07,12)(0.08,13)(0.09,15) (0.10,17)
 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could you please boil down that code to a [complete but minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? I'm 100% sure a lot of these package imports are not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the xtick label style to get the desired format or to override the style chosen. An example is on page 23 of the pgfplots manual. The code below gives you the desired output:

```
\documentclass[x11names,svgnames,11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{axis}[
title={Ballistic Galvanometer Calibration},
xlabel={Capacitance ($\mu$F)},
ylabel={Deflectance (cm)},
xmin=0, xmax=0.12, 
xticklabel style={
  /pgf/number format/precision=3,
  /pgf/number format/fixed},
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
yminorgrids=true,
xminorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[only marks, color=blue, mark=square]
 coordinates {
  (0.01,2)
  (0.02,4)
  (0.03,5)
  (0.04,7)
  (0.05,8)
  (0.06,10)
  (0.07,12)
  (0.08,13)
  (0.09,15)
  (0.10,17)
 };
  \addplot[no marks] {163*x+0.3333 } ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I calculated the linear regression coefficients outside pgfplots. Here is the graph:
[image: Graph]

Comment: Ah, I did get the y=163x+0.333 in excel, didn't think I would been able to add it to the plot that way, thanks!